# Knockout JS Checkbox binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am having an issue with a checkbox binding and a computed observable while jquery is in the page.

```
self.Guaranteed = ko.computed(function() {
    var result;
    result = self.IsGuaranteed() && (self.IsAllowed() || self.IsAllowed2());
    console.log("evaluated");
    if (result) {
        self.IsGuaranteed(false);
    }
    return result;
}, self);
```

[jsfiddle of runnable code](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7vR/)

So I get expected behavior when I don't include jquery in the page, but when jquery is on the page, dependencies do not get correctly registered in the computed observable and the guaranteed checkbox will never uncheck when the condition is met.  The conditional text may or may not show up, depending on if the computed recalculates.  I can't just get rid of jquery form the page unfortunately, any other ideas?

EDIT:

This is the same example as above with expected behavior, but no jQuery loaded: [working jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7vR/4/)

Also, here are the lines in knockout that are resetting the checkbox back:

```
// For click events on checkboxes, jQuery interferes with the event handling in an awkward way:
// it toggles the element checked state *after* the click event handlers run, whereas native
// click events toggle the checked state *before* the event handler.
// Fix this by intecepting the handler and applying the correct checkedness before it runs.
var originalHandler = handler;
handler = function(event, eventData) {
    var jQuerySuppliedCheckedState = this.checked;
    if (eventData)
        this.checked = eventData.checkedStateBeforeEvent !== true;
    originalHandler.call(this, event);
    this.checked = jQuerySuppliedCheckedState; // Restore the state jQuery applied
};
```

Comment: [Putting jQuery Into No-Conflict Mode](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) and avoiding conflicts with other libraries.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you are modifying the computed dependency `self.IsGuaranteed` inside the computed. See the section [Note: Why circular dependencies aren’t meaningful.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

Comment: Show what you've got it bound to.

Comment: The no conflict idea has no effect as I never even use jQuery in my simple example above.  When debugging, there is a section in the knockout code where it tries to compensate for how jquery handles events and that is where the checkbox was getting reset back to true when it should be false.  Still not sure why the other checboxes are not getting registered as dependncies though.

Comment: Can you better explain what exactly you are trying to do? It's exactly clear. But rather than uncheck your `IsGuaranteed` checkbox when it's not valid, why don't you actually disable it? That would avoid your circular dependency and give a better user experience as a user doesn't expect to check something - see it checked - and then have it suddenly become unchecked. If I can't check it, don't let me check it in the first place.

Comment: I tried changing it to a disable and remove the circular dependency as suggested in the answer below but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you would be getting the "correct" behavior considering this pattern, within a computed, needs special consideration. The problem is that you are modifying the computed dependency `self.IsGuaranteed` inside the computed. See [Note: Why circular dependencies aren’t meaningful](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). If you 'must' use this setup, then take into consideration the advice within the link of using `peek`.

This may be a simplified example of a more complex setup, but if the desired functionality is to prevent `guaranteed` from being selected, why not just disable the element?

### Model

```
self.isGuaranteeable = ko.computed(function(){         
    return  !(self.IsAllowed() || self.IsAllowed2());  
});
```

### Html

```
<input data-bind="checked: IsGuaranteed, enable: isGuaranteeable"   id="IsGuaranteed" name="IsGuaranteed" type="checkbox" value="true"> <span>Guaranteed</span>
```

### Explanation

Have a look at your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/u5FRZ/) with some debug capabilities added.

**Case 1**: You select either `Allowed` and then select `Guaranteed`. Next click to print the `isGuaranteed` observable value.

```
[09:45:00.623] Computing (computed)
[09:45:00.623] IsGuaranteed: (assigning) false
[09:45:00.623] IsGuaranteed: (assigning) true
[09:45:38.430] Actual value: false
```

When you entered the computed the value of `IsGuaranteed` was being set to true. You encountered the state you are trying to prevent and set the observable to false. The problem however, **"Knockout will not restart evaluation of a computed while it is already evaluating"**. The span rendered on the "first" pass of the computed and the reassignment of the computed dependency did not trigger a re-evaluation. Thus, the text stays on the screen. You interrupted the original value setting of true which resolves last leaving the checkbox selected but the actual value behind the scenes is `false`.

**Case 2**: Select `Guaranteed`, then either `Allowed` followed by a print of the actual value.

```
[09:58:01.367] Computing (computed)
[09:58:01.367] IsGuaranteed: (assigning) true
[09:58:02.199] Computing (computed)
[09:58:02.199] IsGuaranteed: (assigning) false
[09:58:03.054] Actual value: false
```

The first selection triggers everything appropriately. The selection of the `Allowed` forces the computed to evaluate and the "bad" state triggers the reassignment of `IsGuaranteed`. Since that value was not the original trigger of the computed, it assigns the value correctly, however, the backend is now in a state that should hide the warning text but it did not due to the circular dependency.

Comment: I added your suggestion above with the enable binding to my nonworking fiddle above and it still does not work.  I think the problem is still stemming from the jQuery detection snippet that I posted in my edit.  My issues is not the display of the text, that is secondary, the issue is that checking the allowed or allowed2 checkboxes never causes the computed to evaluate when jquery is in the page.

Comment: well I got it working in a different fiddle somehow even though it didn't work in my original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8t7sm/1/  Thanks!

Comment: Did you have jQuery added to the one you were having trouble with?

Comment: Yeah, jquery was in that fiddle

Comment: Hmmm... not sure then, but cheers! on it working now. One bit of consideration, use Matt Burland's suggestion for subscriptions to uncheck `Guaranteed` if it happens to be already selected when either `Allowed` is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Still not entirely clear on how you actually want this to work, but here's my take on what I *think* you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7vR/7/

I created a separate `computed` to control the `enable` status of the `Guaranteed` checkbox:

```
self.isEnabled = ko.computed(function() {
    return !self.IsAllowed() && !self.IsAllowed2();
});
```

Then I removed the dependency of `IsGuaranteed` on `Guaranteed`:

```
self.Guaranteed = ko.computed(function() {
    var result;
    result = (self.IsAllowed() || self.IsAllowed2());
    console.log("evaluated");
    if (result) {
        self.IsGuaranteed(false);
    }
    return result;
}, self);
```

Now if you click either `Allowed` or `Allowed2` then `Guaranteed` will be disabled. If `Guaranteed` is checked and then you check one of the other checkboxes, `Guaranteed` will become unchecked (and disabled).

Not sure if that was exactly what you wanted to achieve (if not, you need to explain *exactly* what you want) - but note, I wouldn't use a computed property to uncheck the `IsGuaranteed` checkbox. I would instead subscribe to the `IsAllowed` and `IsAllowed2` properties and change the `IsGuaranteed` property there.